# How to receive an array of an object this.NavParam.get("some string")

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I am having the JSON data

```
var productName = [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "productName": "BMW",
        "productImage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/44/BMW.svg/600px-BMW.svg.png",
        "seller": "B",
        "discount": 10,
        "price": 100,
        "data": {
          "subCategory":[

            {
            "name" : "Two Wheeler",
            "productImage" : "http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg",
            },

            {
            "name" : "Four Wheeler",
            "productImage" : "http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg",
            },

            {
            "name" : "Farm Equipment",
            "productImage" : "http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg",        
            }

          ]
        }  
      },
```

I am using the click function in Home.html

```
<ion-slide (click)="infoBrandItem(catName.data);">
 </ion-slide>
```

// implementing the fuction

```
infoBrandItem(catName) {
    this.logger.info("invoking Brand item");
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductSubCategoryPage, catName);
    this.logger.debug("cat name object" +JSON.stringify(catName))
  }
```

I am able to print the subcategory data in my console.How to receive the 'subCategory' details of JSON in my subcategory page. passing the parameter NavParams

// subcategory.ts

```
 _this.catName = this.navParams.get('data');
 _this.logger.debug("printing data " + _this.catName);
```

// subcategory.html

```
<ion-item> {{ catName }}</ion-item>
```

I am getting the output in console as

INFO: invoking Brand item
logger.ts:24 DEBUG: cat name object{"subCategory":[{"name":"Two Wheeler","productImage":"http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg"},{"name":"Four Wheeler","productImage":"http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg"},{"name":"Farm Equipment","productImage":"http://im.rediff.com/money/2011/jul/01car12.jpg"}]}

DEBUG: printing data undefined

How to receive data in my subcategorypage .Please see my updated question

Comment: you previously got {{catName.productName}} which is a level up from subCategory... so wouldn't you be able to access that data by {{catName.data.subCategory}}? But you still need to iterate through those because it's an array of name, productImage

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
*ngFor="let catName of brandName" (click)="infoBrandItem(catName);"
```

You're sending the `catName` which represents this part of the JSON

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "productName": "BMW",
  ...
  ...
},
```

And that's why when you print it

```
_this.logger.debug("printing data " + _this.catName);
```

You see `[object Object]`.

If you want to access the `subcategory` data, you'll have first to obtain that array by doing `_this.catName.data.subCategory`. But keep in mind that it is an array, so if you want to print the details of each element you'll have to use a loop like

```
for(let i=0; i<_this.catName.data.subCategory.length; i++) {
  _this.logger.debug("printing data " + this.catName.data.subCategory[i].name);
}
```

Comment: I am using `NavParams` i passing the `catName` object from my first page and then in second page using navParams i am reciving the object. so, i am not able to get as an string i will be getting only object for example in the receiver of my navParams page i will be using something like this. `this.navCtrl.get('name');` so i will be getting only one string at a time not the entire object

Comment: catName is nothing but the object itself i am passing as a parameter which as like this `[Object Object]` inside my first page

Comment: Could you please add to the OP **all your code**? Both the home.ts, home.html, subcategory.html and subcategory.ts, because right now, it's not easy to understand what the parameters are (you use `catName` several times but the content is not the same everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

maybe set public variable `products` and store there your array of products and then in the template:

```
<ion-row class="brandNameSlideSize">
        <ion-slides pager [options]="mySlideOptionsCategory">
           <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of products" (click)="infoBrandItem(product);">
               <img class="imageCat" src={{product.productImage}}>
               <p>{{product.productName}}</p>
          </ion-slide>    
        </ion-slides>
      </ion-row>
```

---

you also have misleading variable names like `getProductName` when you are getting array of products not only a product name

this function should be named like `getProducts` or `getCategoryProducts` or similar

you can read about js conventions [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)